# Xamarin Size Limit?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android

Xamarin's website says Visual Studio Community doesn't have a size limit... But when I try to run a test app it says otherwise...

I'm new to Xamarin and app development, but this seem's straight forward. What am I missing?

**Xamarin Website:**

> App Restrictions:
>   None. Unlimited app size.
>   Deploy to public and private app stores.

https://www.xamarin.com/compare-visual-studio

**Visual Studio Error:**

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error       User code size, 2426880 bytes, is larger than 131072 and requires aáBusinessá(or higher) License.   ClientApp           
Error       Using type `Android.Runtime.JNIEnv` requiresáBusinessá(or higher) License.  ClientApp
```

**VS 2015 info**

```
Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2015
Version 14.0.24720.00 Update 1
Microsoft .NET Framework
Version 4.6.01038

Installed Version: Community

Visual Basic 2015   00322-20000-00000-AA885
Microsoft Visual Basic 2015

Visual C# 2015   00322-20000-00000-AA885
Microsoft Visual C# 2015

Visual C++ 2015   00322-20000-00000-AA885
Microsoft Visual C++ 2015

Application Insights Tools for Visual Studio Package   1.0
Application Insights Tools for Visual Studio

ASP.NET and Web Tools 2015.1 (Beta8)   14.1.11106.0
ASP.NET and Web Tools 2015.1 (Beta8)

ASP.NET Web Frameworks and Tools 2012.2   4.1.41102.0
For additional information, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=309563

ASP.NET Web Frameworks and Tools 2013   5.2.30624.0
For additional information, visit http://www.asp.net/

Common Azure Tools   1.5
Provides common services for use by Azure Mobile Services and Microsoft Azure Tools.

Microsoft Azure Mobile Services Tools   1.4
Microsoft Azure Mobile Services Tools

NuGet Package Manager   3.3.0
NuGet Package Manager in Visual Studio. For more information about NuGet, visit http://docs.nuget.org/.

PreEmptive Analytics Visualizer   1.2
Microsoft Visual Studio extension to visualize aggregated summaries from the PreEmptive Analytics product.

SQL Server Data Tools   14.0.50616.0
Microsoft SQL Server Data Tools

TypeScript   1.7.6.0
TypeScript for Microsoft Visual Studio

Xamarin   4.0.1.96 (dcea9c1)
Visual Studio extension to enable development for Xamarin.iOS and Xamarin.Android.

Xamarin.Android   6.0.1.10 (e98e962)
Visual Studio plugin to enable development for Xamarin.Android.

Xamarin.iOS   9.4.1.24 (47eb74b)
Visual Studio extension to enable development for Xamarin.iOS.
```

Comment: What version of `Xamarin` / `Xamarin.Android` do you have installed?

Comment: `Xamarin   4.0.1.96 (dcea9c1)` / `Xamarin.Android   6.0.1.10 (e98e962)`

Comment: I would try upgrading. That isn't a particularly new version of Xamarin, and the changes to remove the size restriction look like they may have been in a more recent build.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to update to at least the first stable version after the Microsoft acquisition:

Release Notes: [STABLE RELEASE: CYCLE 6 SERVICE RELEASE 3](https://releases.xamarin.com/stable-release-cycle-6-service-release-3/)

Blog: [Xamarin for Everyone](https://blog.xamarin.com/xamarin-for-all)

- Xamarin for Visual Studio 4.0.3.214
- Xamarin.Android 6.0.3.5

But I would update to at least latest stable version:

Review the release notes for stable/beta/alpha/previews here:

- https://releases.xamarin.com